# How to resize a structure array within a structure?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I have resized the array and when I am trying to print the resized content it throws segmentation fault after printing 5 elements.

*I think I am missing initialization of array in the newly added region and that's why its throwing error as it's not able to find the next index.*

But how should I correct it?

***My Code:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct new{
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct score{
  int score;
  struct new* sub_super[];
};

typedef struct score *ext2_filsys;

int ext2fs_get_mem(unsigned long size, void *ptr)
{
  void *pp;
  pp = malloc(size);

  if(!pp)
    return -1;
  memcpy(ptr, &pp, sizeof(pp));
  return 0;
}

/*
 * Free memory
 */
int ext2fs_free_mem(void *ptr)
{
  void *p;

  memcpy(&p, ptr, sizeof(p));
  free(p);
  p = 0;
  memcpy(ptr, &p, sizeof(p));
  return 0;
}

int ext2fs_resize_mem(unsigned long old_size,
                                     unsigned long size, void *ptr)
{
  void *p;

  /* Use "memcpy" for pointer assignments here to avoid problems
   * with C99 strict type aliasing rules. */
  memcpy(&p, ptr, sizeof(p));
  p = realloc(p, size);
  if (!p)
    return -1;
  memcpy(ptr, &p, sizeof(p));
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  ext2_filsys fs;
  int retval = 0;
  retval = ext2fs_get_mem((sizeof(struct score) + 5 * sizeof(struct new)), &fs);
  if(retval)
    return retval;

  memset(fs, 0, (sizeof(struct score) + 5 * sizeof(struct new)));

  int i;

  for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    retval = ext2fs_get_mem(sizeof(struct new), &fs->sub_super[i]);
    fs->sub_super[i]->x = i;
    fs->sub_super[i]->y = 15-i;
  }

  for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("Data at %d = %d and address = %p\n", i, fs->sub_super[i]->x, fs->sub_super[i]);

  ext2_filsys tempfs;


  retval = ext2fs_get_mem(sizeof(struct score), &tempfs);
  if(retval)
    return retval;

  *tempfs = *fs;

  retval = ext2fs_get_mem((5 * sizeof(struct new)), &tempfs->sub_super);
  printf("Pointer of tempfs->sub_super = %p\n", tempfs->sub_super);

  for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    retval = ext2fs_get_mem(sizeof(struct new), &tempfs->sub_super[i]);
    if(retval)
      return retval;
    memcpy(tempfs->sub_super[i], fs->sub_super[i], sizeof(struct new));
  }

  for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("Data at %d = %d and address = %p\n", i, tempfs->sub_super[i]->x, tempfs->sub_super[i]);

  printf("================================================================\n");
  retval = ext2fs_resize_mem(5 * sizeof(struct new), 10 * sizeof(struct new), &tempfs->sub_super);
  if(retval)
    return retval;


  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("Data at %d = %d and address = %p\n", i, tempfs->sub_super[i]->x, tempfs->sub_super[i]);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(&p, ptr, sizeof(p));` Why not just `p = ptr;`? There is no aliasing problem; even more as you instantly overwrite `p` anyway. That is not the only "strange" code here. You seem to have fundamental missunderstanding how pointer work. - No offence! (Truely none)

Comment: `p = realloc(p, size)`...bad, very bad. Horror starts when `realloc()` fails,

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: these methods are copied from Linux file system. I am making a small change in that and it isn't working. So, I tried to recreate the same scenario in a test program. code is failing when I am trying to do printf at the end.

Comment: @yguw Point 1. The above comment is a _comment_, not an answer, so just treat it like a suggestion. Point 2. Irrespective of the occurrence of the code, its a bad code. You may want to read up about the failure scenario of `realloc()` in detail to understand more.

Comment: @Olaf - These methods are copied from a file system code and I am trying to test few things by making some changes and unfortunately these methods you have pointed out are in the code from a long time.

Comment: So turn of your own reason and think for yourself. Not all code you find is good code. Fact is you have memory leaking like a hairtrap.